# Settings number source from mail() sms

Tags: php, sms

I am sending SMS via php mail() function to an address resembling

`1234567890@txt.att.net`

Everything works great but I would like the ability to change the source number so that when I get the message the number displayed is always consistent.

Is this possible?

I have no interest in using API's or paid or free services. Is this possible to change in the headers or will I have to jump through several hoops to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. This would obviously be chaos if you could, since everyone would be sending texts while pretending to be someone else.

Comment: So how is this number decided?

Comment: there are paid gateways where you can 'buy' a number

Comment: When you send an email to @txt.att.net, AT&T's receiving email server forwards the message through one of *their* SMS gateways, which they have assigned special numbers to. You cannot change these.

Answer (score 0):

will *entirely* depend on the sms gateway you use.

Comment: I am sending through my own server. Is this configurable somehow?